# Probability of picking a quarter from 4 coins ( 2 quarters and 2 loonies)

Tags: probability

Your pocket contains 2 quarters and 2 loonies. If you randomly extract one of the coins and dont replace it and pick a second coin, what is the probability of getting a quarter both times?

Comment: Who mixes US and Canadian currency like this ಠ_ಠ

Comment: You multiply the possibilities together to get ${1\over2}\cdot{1\over3}={1\over6}$. In your case which is small you can list every single possibilities as well.

Comment: @morphic We have quarters too lol

Comment: HAHA thanks! yes canada has both too!

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of getting a quarter in the first draw is 1/2 (well, 2/4 ....).  Assuming that occurred then you are left with 1 quarter in 3 coins.  The odds of drawing a quarter the second time is 1/3.  So prob is 1/2* 1/3 = 1/6.